# Calling a service within an observable subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript

Service1.ts

```
public allFlags$: BehaviorSubject<FlagName> = new BehaviorSubject<FlagName>("feature-flag-1");
```

which is set like this:

```
    private _setFlags = () => {
    const allFlags = this._ldClient.allFlags();

    if (allFlags && Object.keys(allFlags).length > 0
        || (!isUndefinedOrNullOrEmpty(localStorage.getItem(LocalStorageKeys.LaunchDarklyFlags)
            && JSON.stringify(allFlags) !== localStorage.getItem(LocalStorageKeys.LaunchDarklyFlags)))
       ) {
      this._flags = allFlags;
      // Notify the subscribers just in case someone is watching this
      // before setup completes.
      this.allFlags$.next(this._flags);
      localStorage.setItem(LocalStorageKeys.LaunchDarklyFlags, JSON.stringify(this._flags));
    }
  }
```

And it is consumed on the component like this:
Component1.ts

```
this._launchDarklyService.allFlags$.subscribe(flags => this._allFeatureFlags(flags))

private _allFeatureFlags = (flags: FlagName): void => {
    flags = JSON.parse(this._launchDarklyService.getAllFlags())

    if (!(flags && Object.keys(flags).length === 0)) {
        let err = new WebClientException();
        err.ErrorMessage = 'LaunchDarkly- AllFlags- ' + JSON.stringify(flags);
        err.LogType = LogType.INFO;
        this._observable = this._userService.reportError(err)
                            .subscribe();
    }
}
```

The issue here is since I am subscribing(making a post call) inside an Observable subscribe, as a result there are multiple logs in the EventLogger. How can I fix this?

Comment: why are you calling another service inside subscribe? you should use switchMap or mergeMap according to your requirement.

Comment: I agree with @vaibhavshanker, sounds like a job for switchMap. One problem I've noticed is that you're setting this._observable to a subscription, not an observable.

Comment: @MichaelRentmeister, I need to skip the initial value of BehaviourSubject and make an http.post call.

Comment: Apart from the skip as @vaibhavshanker suggest, you could also just use a regular subject instead, if you aren't needing the initial value.

Comment: @MichaelRentmeister, Won't that cause late subscription issue?

Comment: In this scenario, the only reason to use skip(1) instead of a plain subject is if you need to use the .value property of BehaviorSubject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is only fire 1 http call - `this._userService.reportError(err)` each time `allFlags$` observable pushes next data. There are multiple ways to achieve this - I'd look into rxjs's [take](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/take) for how you can only listen for first data from observable.
Something like `this.userService.reportError(err).pipe(take(1)).subscribe()`

Or you can turn that observable into a promise through [toPromise()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/topromise) method, which only emit once and then complete

Alternatively, since calls to `.subscribe()` return you a way to unsubscribe, you can call that method after your first subscription resolves:
`const unsubscriber = myApiCall.subscribe(() => unsubscriber.unsubscribe());`

Comment: In that case since I am using a BehaviourSubject won't it take only the 1st value when nothing is pushed?

Comment: Yes - when using behavior subject, any time something subscribes to it, they will get the last emitted value by the behavior subject, as well as any updated values until the subscriber unsubscribes. If you don't want that 1st value, you can use normal Subject instead.

Comment: If I use a Subject won't there be an issue of late subscription, because component subscribe to the Observable later and the service emits values before the component is ready.

Comment: Yes - So if you want last emitted value when component subscribes, BehaviorSubject is what you want. If you want last emitted value except the absolute very first value from observable stream, in your case, 'feature-flag-1', one pattern I've seen is to simply initialize your behavior subject with null or some NOOP value, and ignore such values. If you want ALL previously emitted values when component subscribes, then maybe replay subject is what you want.